# How do you recreate these structs in Python

Tags: python, struct

I have these two nested structs in C below

```
typedef struct tag_interest {
   float *high;// array
   float *low;// array
} sinterest;

typedef struct tag_sfutures {
   int time;
   float result;
   sinterest *interest;// array
} sfutures;
```

What is there equivalent in Python?

**EDIT**
I had tried this. I am yet to parse and check this because am still in the process of debugging some code that comes before this.

```
class CInterest(object):
    high = []
    low = []
    def add_high(self,High):
        self.high.append(High)
    def add_low(self,Low):
        self.low.append(Low)

class CFutures(object):
    interest = [CInterest]
    def add_interest(self,interest):
        self.interest.append(interest)
    def set_time(self,time):
        self.time = time
    def set_put(self,put):
        self.put = put
```

Comment: @soon please see edits

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at cstruct.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cstruct

It will take your struct definition as a string and create a Python class you can use, instantiate and pack/unpack binary data. I use it to auto generate hundreds of C structures with no issues other than its list of C primitives is not comprehensive.

Comment: sharing link is not a good answer, please share more detail of your solution

Comment: Figuring this out should be simple enough. I provide help and hints, but I will not solve the problem.

Comment: so better put it as a comment not answer